# VBA project explorer: colour settings?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change the shade of my active module (the one I'm editing the code of) as it appears in the project explorer in VBA? With my current setting, the module I'm editing is shaded a very light grey in the project explorer pane at the top left. Thanks

Comment: Oops found it! control panel, personalisation, window colour, 3d objects.

Comment: Or are you looking for VBA Tools|Options|Editor Format?

Comment: Hi thanks, the editor format changes some stuff but not this particular shading. The 3d object did that for me. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops found it! control panel, personalisation, window colour, 3d objects